# What is the style of click onclicking?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm glad you can help me. I want to use css, html, and javascript to draw the text inside the p tag when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: you have some code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a specific code right now, but I want the line to be drawn on the text when the check box is ticked, and when the check is removed, the line to be removed from the text again. Thank you for helping, my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a working example for showing the checked and un-checked status of checkbox:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Checkbox demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>Checkbox:</span> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">
        <p id="result">Page loaded</p>
        <script>
          function myFunction() {
            var checkBox = document.getElementById("my-checkbox");
            var result = document.getElementById("result");
            if (checkBox.checked == true){
              result.innerHTML = "Checkbox was checked"
            } else {
              result.innerHTML = "Checkbox was un-checked"
            }
          }
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
input:checked {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="male" name="gender"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender"> Female<br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Car"> I have a car 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```